How to send JSON array filled with data from Flutter to API made with php
I am currently working on a project and I have come across a problem with sending JSON array to PHP API
Here is the code I wrote for the flutter app:
class AddDeviceFormScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController deviceNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceClusterController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceGeolocation1Controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceGeolocation2Controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController sensorWater1LevelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController sensorWater2LevelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController sensorWater3LevelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController sensorLevel1AlertLevelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceWiFiNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceWiFiPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController deviceMACController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Страница за добавяне на устройсво'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceNameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Име на устройство'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Полето е задължително';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceDescriptionController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Описание на устройство'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceClusterController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Принадлежност към клъстер'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Полето е задължително';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceGeolocation1Controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Геолокация / Географска ширина'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceGeolocation2Controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Геолокация / Географска дължина'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: sensorWater1LevelController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Критично ниво за известяване на сензор 1'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: sensorWater2LevelController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Критично ниво за известяване на сензор 2'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: sensorWater3LevelController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Критично ниво за известяване на сензор 3'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: sensorLevel1AlertLevelController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Критично ниво за известяване на ултразвуков сензор(в метри)'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"[+-]?\d+").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceWiFiNameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Име на безжичната мрежа'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Полето е задължително';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceWiFiPasswordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Парола за безжичната мрежа'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Полето е задължително';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: deviceMACController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'MAC адрес / сериен номер на устройството'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || !RegExp(r"([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})").hasMatch(value.trim())) {
                      return 'Невалидна стойност';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    print('Button pressed');
                    if (Form.of(context).validate()) {
                      // Collect form data
                      Map<String, dynamic> formData = {
                        'device_name1': deviceNameController.text,
                        'device_description1': deviceDescriptionController.text,
                        'device_cluster1': deviceClusterController.text,
                        'device_geolocation11': deviceGeolocation1Controller.text,
                        'device_geolocation21': deviceGeolocation2Controller.text,
                        'sensor_water_1_level_1': sensorWater1LevelController.text,
                        'sensor_water_2_level_1': sensorWater2LevelController.text,
                        'sensor_water_3_level_1': sensorWater3LevelController.text,
                        'sensor_level_1_alert_level_1': sensorLevel1AlertLevelController.text,
                        'device_wifi_network_name1': deviceWiFiNameController.text,
                        'device_wifi_network_password1': deviceWiFiPasswordController.text,
                        'device_mac1': deviceMACController.text,
                      };

                      // Print the collected form data (for debugging purposes)
                      print('Form Data: $formData');

                      // Send data to the PHP backend
                      await sendFormDataToApi(formData);

                      // Navigate back to the previous screen
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Добави устройство'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Reset form fields
                    deviceNameController.clear();
                    deviceDescriptionController.clear();
                    deviceClusterController.clear();
                    deviceGeolocation1Controller.clear();
                    deviceGeolocation2Controller.clear();
                    sensorWater1LevelController.clear();
                    sensorWater2LevelController.clear();
                    sensorWater3LevelController.clear();
                    sensorLevel1AlertLevelController.clear();
                    deviceWiFiNameController.clear();
                    deviceWiFiPasswordController.clear();
                    deviceMACController.clear();
                  },
                  child: Text('Отказ'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> sendFormDataToApi(Map<String, dynamic> formData) async {
    final apiUrl = 'http://kvb-bg.com/Sirena/test_api_adding_devices.php';

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        body: formData,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Handle the response if needed
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to add device');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error: $e');
    }
  }
}


and here is the code for the API in PHP:
<?php

$inputJSON = file_get_contents("php://input");

// Define the request method
$requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

// Output the request method and input JSON
if ($requestMethod === 'GET') {
    // Handle GET request parameters
    $input = json_decode($inputJSON);
} elseif ($requestMethod === 'POST') {
    // Handle POST request JSON payload
    $input = json_decode($inputJSON);
} else {
    // If it's neither GET nor POST, return an error response
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Unsupported request method";
    exit();
}

// Process the input data based on the request method
$deviceName = isset($input->device_name1) ? $input->device_name1 : '';
$deviceDescription = isset($input->device_description1) ? $input->device_description1 : '';
$deviceCluster = isset($input->device_cluster1) ? $input->device_cluster1 : '';
$deviceGeolocation1 = isset($input->device_geolocation11) ? $input->device_geolocation11 : '';
$deviceGeolocation2 = isset($input->device_geolocation21) ? $input->device_geolocation21 : '';
$sensorWater1Level = isset($input->sensor_water_1_level_1) ? $input->sensor_water_1_level_1 : '';
$sensorWater2Level = isset($input->sensor_water_2_level_1) ? $input->sensor_water_2_level_1 : '';
$sensorWater3Level = isset($input->sensor_water_3_level_1) ? $input->sensor_water_3_level_1 : '';
$sensorLevel1AlertLevel = isset($input->sensor_level_1_alert_level_1) ? $input->sensor_level_1_alert_level_1 : '';
$deviceWiFiName = isset($input->device_wifi_network_name1) ? $input->device_wifi_network_name1 : '';
$deviceWiFiPassword = isset($input->device_wifi_network_password1) ? $input->device_wifi_network_password1 : '';
$deviceMAC = isset($input->device_mac1) ? $input->device_mac1 : '';

// Database operations
if ($requestMethod === 'GET' || $requestMethod === 'POST') {
    // Connect to your MySQL database
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "kvbbgcom_floodPrevention"; // Replace with your MySQL username
    $password = "kv0889909595"; // Replace with your MySQL password
    $dbname = "kvbbgcom_floodPrevention"; // Replace with your MySQL database name

    // Create a connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Output received data
    echo "Device Name: $deviceName\n";
    echo " ";
echo "Device Description: $deviceDescription\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device Cluster: $deviceCluster\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device Geolocation 1: $deviceGeolocation1\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device Geolocation 2: $deviceGeolocation2\n";
echo " ";
echo "Sensor Water 1 Level: $sensorWater1Level\n";
echo " ";
echo "Sensor Water 2 Level: $sensorWater2Level\n";
echo " ";
echo "Sensor Water 3 Level: $sensorWater3Level\n";
echo " ";
echo "Sensor Level 1 Alert Level: $sensorLevel1AlertLevel\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device WiFi Name: $deviceWiFiName\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device WiFi Password: $deviceWiFiPassword\n";
echo " ";
echo "Device MAC: $deviceMAC\n";
echo " ";
    // Similarly, output other received data

    // $sql = "INSERT INTO devices (device_name, device_description, device_cluster, device_geolocation_1, device_geolocation_2, sensor_water_1_level, sensor_water_2_level, sensor_water_3_level, sensor_level_1_alert_level, device_wifi_network_name, device_wifi_network_password, device_mac)
// VALUES ('$deviceName', '$deviceDescription', '$deviceCluster', '$deviceGeolocation1', '$deviceGeolocation2', '$sensorWater1Level', '$sensorWater2Level', '$sensorWater3Level', '$sensorLevel1AlertLevel', '$deviceWiFiName', '$deviceWiFiPassword', '$deviceMAC')";

// Execute the SQL statement
// if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//     echo "New record created successfully";
// } else {
//     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
// }
    // Close the database connection
    $conn->close();
}

// Output the input JSON
var_dump($inputJSON);

exit();
?>


it gives me this when I open the API: Device Name: Device Description: Device Cluster: Device Geolocation 1: Device Geolocation 2: Sensor Water 1 Level: Sensor Water 2 Level: Sensor Water 3 Level: Sensor Level 1 Alert Level: Device WiFi Name: Device WiFi Password: Device MAC: string(0) ""

What do you get with var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) and var_dump($inputJSON)? That last bit in your question is telling you that you're trying to insert something into a column which doesn't exist. Also, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared queries to handle everything that's coming from the outside and going into your DB.

i am not entirely sure, but chat-gpt says: var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) will output the HTTP request method used to access the PHP script. This could be 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', etc., depending on how the script is accessed.
var_dump($inputJSON) will output the contents of the JSON payload received in the request body. This payload is read using file_get_contents("php://input") and then decoded using json_decode().

`<?php
<?php` would result in a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<"...
<?php <?php was just a copy error
What I meant was this - add the two lines at the top of your code, right after you declare $inputJSON, and then exit(); or die();, and see what you get.

now after adding exit(), it returns me: string(3) "GET" string(0) ""

Because you are using the HTTP version of the URL for your request, but you have an automatic redirect to the HTTPS version in place. (And when the browser follows that redirect, it switches from POST to GET.)

so i have to have an ssl serificate and https url to make it redirect to the api url?

Looks like you already have! Have you tried using https://kvb-bg.com... in your code, so no redirect occurs?

i have just tried, but no difference: 'Future sendFormDataToApi(Map<String, dynamic> formData) async {
final apiUrl = 'https://kvb-bg.com/Sirena/test_api_adding_devices.php';
try {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(apiUrl),
    body: formData,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Handle the response if needed
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to add device');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Error: $e');
}

}
}'

Just tested, using a <form> to post to your url is working fine, so I guess it has to be something with your flutter code, never used it though so I'm out. Good luck

Not the best practice (since you won't resolve what's causing the method change), but you can do the following. In your PHP code, check for the server request method. If it's GET, do stuff like $deviceName = isset($_GET['device_name1']) ? $_GET['device_name1'] : ''; and so on. If it's POST do the same thing, but with POST. If it's neither of the two, return an error response.

@FiddlingAway i tried it, and it gives me: Device Name: Device Description: Device Cluster: Device Geolocation 1: Device Geolocation 2: Sensor Water 1 Level: Sensor Water 2 Level: Sensor Water 3 Level: Sensor Level 1 Alert Level: Device WiFi Name: Device WiFi Password: Device MAC: string(0) ""

Are you sure that your Flutter application is actually outputting what you expect it to? Does print('Form Data: $formData'); print the expected contents to the screen?

the thing is that, it does not print anything on the screen. I tried using Dartpad to see if it would make any difference, but it did not :/

OK, let's try this. Convert your $formData to a JSON, and then send that to your PHP. For example: String jsonFormData = jsonEncode(formData); await sendFormDataToApi(jsonFormData); - also change what's printing to the screen, so that it prints out the JSON, and not the original Map . If you do this, you would also need to import 'dart:convert' at the top of your code, and later on, in your sendFormDataToApi, specify the headers as application/json.
